# Gatling throws NullPointerException (HttpProtocol.scala:71)

Tags: gatling

I'm building a basic Gatling load test using Intellij/sbt and having trouble getting a basic query to run.

Here's my code:

```
package basicly

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object gat extends Simulation {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("HELLO TEST")
    val httpConf = http
      .baseURL("https://api.myurl.io")//exception starts here
      .basicAuth("uname", "pword")
      .userAgentHeader("bodhi-agent/v1")
val scn = scenario("Upload a file")
  .exec(http("homepage_GET")
    .get("/namespace/resources/Timecard")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
  .pause(5)

setUp(
  scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf)
)
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get this trace:

> HELLO TEST Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocol$.apply(HttpProtocol.scala:71)
>     at
>   io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocolBuilder$.apply(HttpProtocolBuilder.scala:42)
>     at io.gatling.http.HttpDsl$class.http(HttpDsl.scala:36)     at
>   io.gatling.http.Predef$.http(Predef.scala:18)     at
>   basicly.gat$.main(gat.scala:14)   at basicly.gat.main(gat.scala)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

It's failing on line 14, which starts "val httpConf = http"

I'm new to Gatling so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117321/debugging-the-session/40221550#40221550) if you just want to execute or debug the simulation from your IDE.

Answer (score -2):

In the documentation, there is nowhere mentioned that it's possible to launch a Simulation directly from an Object's main method. For a very good reason: it's not!

Comment: Well ... that's extremely helpful. Now I know what I can't do. This is the kind of answer that keeps me coming back to Stackoverflow