# Debugging the session

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

As part of my performance testing, I need to debug the session etc. The same code is running if I remove `session =>`. When I add that it says there was no request sent during simulation since it is not sending any.

```
 val scn1 = scenario("LaunchAction").exec{ session => 

   http("Poll report status page report")
     .get("myURL/rest/reports")
     .queryParam("applicationId", "123")          
     .queryParam("id", "1")
     .check(xpath("//status").saveAs("responseStatus"))

   session
}
```

I need to add few prints etc in between. Can you please provide some information?

Comment: Though I found out that we cant do that within the exec block .. but another way to print out more information is to change the logger level to DEBUG in logback.xml

Answer (score 8):

I just started with Gatling and I had exactly the same problem.
The easiest way to debug for me was the addition of the entrypoint object, which I use to start/debug tests locally by running the main method

```
object DebugEntrypoint {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // This sets the class for the Simulation we want to run.
    val simClass = classOf[Smoke].getName

    val props = new GatlingPropertiesBuilder
    props.sourcesDirectory("./src/test/scala")
    props.binariesDirectory("./target/scala-2.10/classes")
    props.simulationClass(simClass)
    Gatling.fromMap(props.build)
  }
}
```

As soon as the test is being executed from here, any breakpoints I put in the simulation will pause execution during the runtime. As soon as you hit a breakpoint, you can evaluate expressions and have all other debug instruments at your bidding.

Comment: Thanks man! I was looking for this for a while. It's working. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another exec to it like this:

```
.exec(
      session => {
        val activityId = session.get("someId").asOption[String]
        println(activityId)
        session
      }
    )
```

This should give you the session details.

Answer (score 0):

one more thing you can do for the debug purpose in conf folder of Gatling 
there would be one file logback.xml in which you had to uncomment the two lines
    
    
after uncommenting these lines you would get every request while running in browser in detailed way which will help you in order to solve the query